# How to pass powershell variable value to cmd.exe?

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am trying to install a service 'ServiceName' from the command prompt, with parameter values which I am taking as user input forms through powershell.

```
$server = $return[0]

Invoke-Expression -Command "cmd.exe /c ServiceName --install --server=$server"
```

Basically the ServiceName service takes parameter values from server variable while installing. I am not exactly sure if this is the correct way of using powershell variable values in cmd.exe. Can the cmd.exe take in the server variable value in the manner shown above?

Answer (score 0):

You can add new services in Powershell, and you dont have to use cmd for that:

```
$serviceName= Read-Host("Enter service name")
$mycreds = Get-Credential
$binaryPath = Read-Host("Enter service executable path")
New-Service -name $serviceName -binaryPathName $binaryPath -displayName $serviceName -startupType Automatic -credential $mycreds
```

Also you can use

```
Get-Help New-Service
```

If you want additional parameters passed to the command. Or if you want, you can parse if from a single input, but its more messy.

Comment: Thankyou for the help. I have one more query. Is there any way of checking the service parameters of a specific service using powershell?

Comment: Sorry, not that i know of a way. Its individual per service. You can however pass arguments in the binary path variable: `new-service -name TestService -binaryPathName "C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs"....`